# TJavaFlex component unable to convert Integer to String error

Tags: java, etl, talend

I am a noob in Talend and I am having a very simple flow as below: A delimited file connected to a tjavaflex component, which is in turn is connected to tlogrow.
[image]

The delimited file has a column "id" defined as integer. I am trying to send this column as a string and also do some transformations(like string append) while sending data into  the tlogrow component.
I have modified the schema of the tlogrow component so that it can receive String values.

[image]

Yet when I run the job,I am getting the error as below:
[image]

When I inspect the code,I find that the error has occurred here:
[image]

At the same time, I don't understand why I have the lines 850,851,852 in the above snip, when ideally ,my code is at lines 854,855,856.

From what I can understand, even though I changed the datatype of my "id" column at the receiving end, it is still considering it as an Integer type.

Can someone please let me know why this error could be occurring? I tried a lot of combinations to get this working somehow, but it doesn't. Even executed similar code snippets in Java(EclipseIDE),but I don't seem to be able to reproduce this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncheck the *Data Auto Propogate* checkbox in the `tJavaFlex` component to prevent the automatic code generation to propagate the input-output flow.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, now I have another issue, the piece of code(essentially a simple print statement) that I have written in the "Start Code" and "end Code" section is appearing together ,followed by the "main code" section. When I debug the job code ,I see that the "Start ","Main" and "End" code are executed in the right order. Why could it be printing differently onto the console ?I believe its an issue with the tlogrow compoent.

Comment: Create another question with the actual and expected output,  this is a different topic.